# WordPress numberposts not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. I have a problem in posts. I want to show latest 4 posts of a category on the home page, but it is displaying the 5 post, as i have added 5 posts.

Here is my code:

```
        <div id="from-categories" class="clearfix">     
        <?php 
        $catName='HomePost';              
        $cat_ID=get_cat_ID($catName);             
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => $cat_ID);              
        $postslist = get_posts( $args );                  
        foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>       
        <div class="recent-cat">            
            <h4 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>            
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>                         
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore">Read More</a>          
        </div>      

        <?php endforeach; ?>            
        </div> <!-- end #from-categories -->
```

Please let me know what is wrong with this code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'category_name' => 'HomePost'
);
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="recent-cat">            
            <h4 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>            
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>                         
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="readmore">Read More</a>          
        </div> 
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this code. I am using TheSource Theme, and did customize the theme for the home page. If i gave the posts_per_page=3 or numberposts=3, still there were 4 posts on the home page. I am not getting the problem either in theme or in my code.

Comment: I have got the problem myself. There is a little mistake in your array declaration: Here is the correct code and its working...$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'cat' => 52,
 'showposts' => 4
); Thanks for the reply.